# Get access to data of component from another component

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I want to get viewModel of 'first-component' from 'second-component' and synchronize self.prop for both components. I use Knockout library. Here is my code:

```
ko.components.register('first-component', {
    template: '<strong><span data-bind="text: prop"></span></strong>',
    viewModel: function(params){
        var self = this;

        self.prop = ko.observable(params.initialText);
    }
});

ko.components.register('second-component', {
template: '<div><input type="text" data-bind="value: prop">' 
          + '<button data-bind="click: foo">Click Me</button></div>',
viewModel: function(params){
        var self = this;

        self.prop = ko.observable(params.initialText);
        self.foo = function(){
        // HELP ME! I want to get viewModel of 'first-component' and 
        // synchronize self.prop for both components
            if(ko.components.isRegistered("first-component")){
            //...???

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Using components in markup:

```
<first-component params="initialText: 'Some text...'"></first-component>

<second-component params="initialText: 'Another text...'"></second-component>
```

Comment: You should put the two components' view model into a parent view model. Then you could use `$root.firstComponentViewModel` and `$root.secondComponentViewModel` to access to those two.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thank you for attention, but you really a strange man, if you asking me about this. 
I need to get viewModel of component programmaticly and update properties of this viewModel.

Comment: @trgiangvp3 Above, I wrote demo code, wich show my actually problem.
In reality, i work with big program, so i can not  change parent viewModel, and it`s very difficult task.

Comment: @ВладимирЗуев Sorry, I missed the triple question mark inside the code while reviewing; Question seems clear. On the question itself: I'don't know anything about knockout.js, but if there is some shared state between the two components, why not extract it into some "model-like" object outside of the two viewModels, and then communicate over this third object?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes, i think so too :) But i don now how to do this in Knockout.js. I can not find some information in official documentation, or examples with code. Apparently, i will search solution in source codes of knockout.js on github.com

Comment: @trgiangvp3 Your solution is working

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Your solution is working too. I think both solutions is same. I use property from parent View Model, and both components communicate behind with this property.

Comment: @ВладимирЗуев trgiangvp3's solution seems to be a specific instantiation of my proposal. My proposal is somewhat less concrete. What I essentially wanted to say: in "knockout.js", there is still ".js". If the library itself does not mandate some specific solution, you can still solve the problem with plain good old JS.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I thought so too, but unfortunately knowledge of plain good old JS is not enough, when you deal with concreate technologies. Becourse, each technology have own API, lifecycle and best practies. So that, if using just JavaScript, it would look as kostyl' :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To facilitate interaction between a components and an external view model, I find the best thing is to pass in an observable as a parameter to manage the synchronization of data.  I've set up a [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/erbronni/aLvowbx2/) using your code above.

The first change is to create a parent view model to contain the shared state between the components

```
var parentViewModel {
  sharedText: ko.observable('shared text')
}
```

Then use the shared text as parameters to the components.  For the first component, the `initialText` is set to the `sharedText`, while the second component, the `sharedText` is passed in as a second parameter.  This is because the shared text is only updated when the "Click Me" button is clicked.  If the `sharedText` observable was set to the `initialText` for both, then the update would happen automatically.  Sometimes this is what is required, sometimes not.

```
<first-component params="initialText: sharedText"></first-component>
<second-component params="initialText: 'Initial value', sharedText: sharedText"></second-component>
```

And then when assigning the property in the first component, use the reference from the `params.initialText` instead of creating new observable.  When knockout binds the HTML, it will bind to the parentViewModel.sharedText and automatically update the HTML anytime parentViewModel.sharedText is updated.

```
ko.components.register('first-component', {
    template: '<strong><span data-bind="text: prop"></span></strong>', 
viewModel: function(params){
        var self = this;
        self.prop = params.initialText;
    }
});
```

In the second component, a new observable is created using the initial text, and the `foo` click handler updates the `params.sharedText` reference using the value from `self.props`.

```
ko.components.register('second-component', {
    template: '<div><input type="text" data-bind="value: prop">' 
      + '<button data-bind="click: foo">Click Me</button></div>',
    viewModel: function(params){
        var self = this;
        self.prop = ko.observable(params.initialText);
        self.foo = function(){
            params.sharedText(self.prop());
        }
    }
});
```

This is very similar to pulling up the state in React components, where the components are passed in a set of properties, including a set of callbacks from the parent component, and the callbacks are responsible for updating the shared view model.

I've also added a third component, because it is very important to dispose of components correctly.  See [Disposal and memory management](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#disposal-and-memory-management) in the component documentation for more details.  The third component is a counter tracking how many times the `sharedText` has been updated.  It uses a subscription on the knockout observable, and if the component is removed from the DOM, then it needs to dispose of the subscription.  If you define a `dispose` function on the component, knockout will automatically call this method when it removes the component from the DOM.

```
ko.components.register('third-component', {
    template: '<div>Counter:&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: count"></span></div>',
  viewModel: function (params) {
     var self = this;
     self.count = ko.observable(0);
     self.sub = params.sharedText.subscribe(function () {
        self.count(self.count() + 1);
     });
     self.dispose = function () {
            self.sub.dispose();
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the best solution for me!